# How do I print the entire url.URL struct?

Tags: go

I have the following https://play.golang.org/p/utnlHJqlX1:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://www.something.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", u)
}
```

I was expecting the "%+v" to print the struct and the fields. Instead it prints: "http://www.something.com"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be because `Parse` is returning a pointer to the struct.

Try with this (note the `*`):

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *u)
```

Modified playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/Grjrp2QriK

**EDIT**

To expand on this, the reason for this is that `fmt` treats structs that implement `Stringer` differently when doing `%+v`.

This is the relevant code: https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=4772:4849#L577

Since `*URL` implements Stringer: https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.String

That's the string being used.

By dereferencing the pointer, we get an `URL`, which does not implement the interface (cause the receiver in the `String` method is a pointer).

Comment: Pointers usually print fine (see p): https://play.golang.org/p/ZrWq2heDl2

Comment: @kristen That's because *P does not implement [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer). [Reference](https://play.golang.org/p/CqWk9nP52a)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `%#v` formatting verb to print the Go syntax representation for any value. For example:

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n",u)
```

This can be handy for debugging & automatic code generation. Since the output is the Go representation, this could be pasted into a test or similar as a variable.

This way you don't need to worry about type that override [fmt.Stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)